# ಠ_ಠ button for chat

Tags: feature-request, chat

I think this would be really useful.  There's a [Chrome plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/look-of-disapproval/cmomlddchhdnchpieaalgkpgaafohlbn?hl=en) that provides some great functionality, but sometimes you just need to break out a disapproving look immediately in another browser, and I think SE chat needs to support this.

Can we have a ಠ_ಠ button please?

[image: ಠ_ಠ]

Comment: Whoever downvotes this hates fun and should be banned.

Comment: ಠ_ಠ​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: `"but sometimes you just need to break out a disapproving look immediately"` I don't see why using a plugin or userscript would delay your expression of disapproval.

Comment: @GnomeSlice It should be possible to write a userscript that works for GreaseMonkey as well as Chrome. If you're using IE, well, ಠ_ಠ.

Comment: that face looks more like it's lacking sleep than disapproving.

Comment: @Spudley it looks better when it's not bolded.

Comment: We all hate fun on Meta

Comment: I'm afraid that this would lead us down the slippery slope towards widespread acceptance of all emoticons.

Comment: Why not just wait for the other users in the room to flag the message as their way of showing their ಠ_ಠ​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: I dispute that such a button would be "fun".  If we are going to have fun on meta, [go for the gusto](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/always-friday-in-iceland?sort=votes)!

Comment: It is not even Friday in Iceland yet...and it is *always* Friday in Iceland.

Comment: (」ﾟヘﾟ)」ಥ_ಥ(⌐■_■)

Comment: Why all the downvotes? ಠ_ಠ​​​​ Do u even chat bro?​​​​​​​​

Comment: @TCPMAN.EXE（−＿−；）

Answer (score 18):

Here's something that should work as a userscript in both GreaseMonkey (Firefox) and Chrome:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name          Disapproval Button
// @author        Asad
// @version       1.0
// @namespace     pleaseletthisbeauniquenamespace
// @description   Grimace disapprovingly more efficiently than ever
// @include       http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/*
// @include       http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/*
// @include       http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/*
// ==/UserScript==


(function go() {
    var buttonsContainer = document.getElementById("chat-buttons"),
        newButton = document.createElement("button");

    newButton.setAttribute("class", "button");
    newButton.id = "disapproval-button";
    newButton.innerHTML = "ಠ_ಠ"

    buttonsContainer.appendChild(newButton);

    newButton.addEventListener("click", function(e){
        var editorCell = this.parentElement.previousElementSibling,
            textarea = editorCell.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0],
            text = textarea.value,
            selStart = textarea.selectionStart,
            selEnd = textarea.selectionEnd;
        textarea.value = text.slice(0, selStart) + "ಠ_ಠ" + text.slice(selEnd);
        textarea.focus();
        textarea.selectionStart = textarea.selectionEnd = selStart + 3;
    });
})();
```

To install in Chrome:

1. Put the snippet above in a file called whateveryoufancy.user.js on your desktop or somewhere
2. Open Tools > Extensions in Chrome and drag the file onto the page you land on.

To install in Firefox + GreaseMonkey, simply drag and drop the file into any browser window.

[image]

Comment: I have no idea how to use this, but thanks I guess.

Comment: @GnomeSlice Let me know if you run into problems.

Comment: It works!  Doesn't auto-focus back to the text back after click, but not a big deal I guess.  Thanks!  =P

Comment: @GnomeSlice Sorry, that was an oversight on my part. Should be fixed now (update your text file with the new version, drag it again).

Comment: I tried to install this on my wife. It did not work. But she did give me this look. So I guess it did work after all.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Try installing it on your wife's browser next time. (More seriously though, what went wrong?)

Comment: @Asad Oh, no; you nailed the problem. So to speak... I was installing it on the Wife, not the Browser! ;)